# Check if photo is updated in Ldap using ruby's NetLdap gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ldap

In my application I sync users image uploaded as photo field in the LDAP.

Is there a way to detect whether the image has changed so that I don't have to upload it to my application every time.

I am looking if there is a way where LDAP says it is modified or LDAP gem can say it. Some timestamp in LDAP.

One way I can think of is storing the MD5 hash in my database for the image data I get from LDAP, so next time I compare it with this MD5 before uploading.

Is there a better way

Answer (score 0):

Most LDAP systems will provide a potential modificationTimestamp attribute, but this is usually object level.  eDirectory actually stores it per attribute.

Comment: ok, then I think I will have to go with my approach.
Thanks for the info @geoffc